# Interactive grid coupled to mysqli table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I am new to programming. I have been learning php and mysqli and I know that this question requires more knowledge than that. I am working on a grid 3 rows by 3 columns. Only up to one square within a raw can be selected.

I want the user to be able to click on a square (called A, B, C within a row) and the square would change a color. As the user clicks, I'd like the row and square info be transmitted to a table in mysqli, ideally. If not, I'd use a submit button.

How would such "complete" code looks like?

Comment: A "complete" code requires that you post an "incomplete" code from your end. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain this without javascript now to keep things easy.

If you already draw the boxes based on your SQL table, you're good to go for this:
Wrap the boxes into `<a>` elements. These links should contain info about their position or id, as well as their state.

For example `<a href='/changeState.php?boxId=1&state=green'></a>`

Then of course you would need the corresponding script changeState.php which accepts `$_GET['boxId]` and `$_GET['state']`, and then does an SQL operation based on this info.

Alternatively you could even use the same URL (that you use to display the grid) and have it handle the MySQL operations if the expected GET parameters are present.

Does this help you?

Comment: Thanks. That would work and it is the simplest solution. I have heard about Ajax but I have no skills to implement Ajax. Here is an example, yet I do not know I can have my selections be posted upon clicking: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/JavascriptDemo/b/build_jquery_ui_selectable_display_as_grid_in_javascript_example.htm

Comment: You should check out https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ and try to get a simple request working.    


After this, you can wrap the post function in a click event attached to all boxes:
https://api.jquery.com/click/    


You'll need to include JQuery in your scripts section for this to work, but I'd highly recommend using it anyway.